# What is the reason to axiomatize "undefined" in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: undefined, isabelle

In Isabelle/HOL, the following axiomatizations can be found

```
axiomatization The :: "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a"
axiomatization undefined :: 'a
```

Is there a reason that one couldn't use

```
definition "undefined ≡ The (λx. False)"
```

or is this just a historic artifact? It seems that the current way leads to "different" notions of undefinedness. I stumbled upon this when I defined something along the lines of

```
definition "of_interest y ≡ (THE x. foobar x y)"
```

and wanted to prove the (in hindsight foolish) sanity-check

```
lemma "(∄x. foobar x y) ⟹ of_interest y = undefined"
```

which obviously doesn't work in the current state, but should go through with the above definition of undefined.

Comment: In Isabelle, every type is inhabited, and `undefined::'a` denotes *some* value of type `'a`, but you cannot know which one it is (and this is precisely what the axiomatization of `undefined` postulates). Therefore, your definition of `undefined` does not capture the intended meaning. It's fair to mention, though, that the choice for the name `undefined` is somewhat unfortunate, you may think of it as `unknown` instead.

Comment: @JavierDíaz I am fully aware of the intended meaning. The question though is: is there anything that can be proved with the existing axiomatization that can not be proven with my proposed alternative? Maybe I missing some additional axioms somewhere that involve undefined. Purely reading the type signature, `The (λx. False)` must also return *some* value of type `'a`. Maybe yet another alternative would be `Eps (λx. True)`?

Comment: I think the purpose of the present definition is precisely that you cannot prove a lot from it. As you say yourself, there would be multiple alternatives in your direction. But what would be a justification to be able to prove equality of `undefined` to `The (λx. False)` but not to, say, `The (λx. True)`?

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Sorry, I got your question wrong. I think that by using the `axiomatization` mechanism you clearly state that you cannot assume anything about `undefined :: 'a` but that it's an arbitrary but unknown value of type `'a`. On the contrary, by using your definition, you now know a bit more about `undefined`, namely that it's the value to which `The` maps `λx. False` (the same applies for `Eps (λx. True)` and similar definitions). For example, with your definition you can prove that `The (λx. False) = undefined`, which you cannot prove using the axiomatization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `axiomatization` mechanism you clearly state that you cannot assume anything about `undefined :: 'a` but that it's an arbitrary but unknown value of type `'a`. On the contrary, by using your definition, you now know a bit more about `undefined`, namely that it's the value to which `The` maps `λx. False` (the same applies for `Eps (λx. True)` and similar definitions). For example, with your definition you can prove that `The (λx. False) = undefined`, which you cannot prove using the `axiomatization`.